Autofill feature not working in safari browser when component re-renders during autofill
I have a component say DropDown and it has an onChangeEventHandler in the select html tag. My parent component which is a address form renders two dropdown component one is for country field and the other is for state field. Initially the form is rendered with pre-select country value IN in the country drop-down and the state drop-down has no pre-selected value as such but the option list of the select tag has all the IN-states. When autofill is triggered with some address that contains some other states say US US the onChange event triggers and changes the selected value from IN to US, and then my parent address component renders to update the child dropdown component with updated field data. The state dropdown now consists of the IN state list in the options of select tag. But the onChange event never gets triggered for the state field in Safari. Hence state field never populated with the autofill value.
When checked in Chrome the onChange event for state gets triggered two times. I believe it because of, one of the first render and one for the fresh render after the country value is updated.
// Address Component - Parent

stores the address in the react state.
Stores country value and country list
Stores adress line 1, phone, email, name
stores state value and state list of the selected country value

setSelectedCountry = (e) =\> {

    1. updates the country value
    2. updates the state list based on the country value
}

// DropDown Component - Child

Stores selected value

onChangeHandler = (e) =\> {
    this.setState({selectedValue: e.target.value})
    this.props.setSelectedCountry(e.target.value) // coming from parent
}

